# How would I associate these models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically I have 4 models,
USERS -> PROJECTS -> ASSETS -> TODOOS

What I am trying to do is make it so that on the user page I can view all the tasks that need to be done (all the todoos), then on the projects page I can view only the tasks associated with that project and on the assets page I want to be able to view all the tasks only associated with that asset. How would I do this? Currently, my columns for ToDoos are:

Id
name
user_id
time

Here are my models

```
#models/user
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :projects
  has_many :assets, through: :projects
  has_many :notes, through: :assets
  has_many :todoos
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Project

```
#models/project
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
   self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

Asset

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

Todoos

```
class Todoo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

Essentially this is what i want to be able to call on each page
User - current_user.todoos
Project - current_user.projects.todoos (or just project.todoos)
Asset - asset.todoos
```

****UPDATE****
Some confusion as to what I am asking. Basically each todo can either be associated with an asset, project, or user. However if the todo is created at an asset level then that todo will be visible at both the project and user level, same with if it is created at a project level, it will be visible at the user level as well. So essentially, what ever model it is first associated with, it will be visible by all other models that are above it in this heirarchy

User

|

Project

|

Asset

Comment: it's not clear what your requirements are.  Are todoos meant to be associated with specific projects and/or assets?  I always start this sort of thing by drawing a very simple diagram like this http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~migod/uml/omniGraffle.jpg - you can skip the method names in the lower part of each box.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I updated to clarify what I meant

Comment: `current_user.todoos` works fine right? youre more concerned with other paths lile `current_user.projects.todoos`?